# How to import interface explicitly in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, import, node-redis

I wonder how to import the interface explicitly in typescript?

In `@types/redis` I have:

```
export const RedisClient: new (options: ClientOpts) => RedisClient;

export interface RedisClient extends Commands<boolean>, EventEmitter {
```

when I add the following import in my code:

```
import { RedisClient } from "redis";
```

constant gets imported, not the interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Typescript 3.8 you can use type-only imports and exports.

In your case it would look like this:

```
import type { RedisClient } from "redis"
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html